# MySQL - grant all privileges on *.* brings back Access denied

Tags: mysql-5.5, permissions

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO  'username'@'localhost'  IDENTIFIED  BY  'somepassword';
```

Brings back error :

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

If I give a database name it works.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON dbname.* TO  'username'@'localhost'  IDENTIFIED  BY  'somepassword';
```

I did `select * from user where user ='root';` and it has `Y` under every `*_priv column`.

I'm running MySQL Server version: 5.5.38. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not upgrade properly try running:

`/usr/bin/mysql_upgrade -u root -p`

Answer (score 3):

For those who still stumble upon this like I did, it's worth checking to make sure the attempted `GRANT` does not already exist:

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR username;
```

In my case, the error was not actually because there was a permission error, but because the `GRANT` already existed.

Answer (score 0):

I just occurred this question and solved it.
I have tried `/usr/bin/mysql_upgrade` and using any kind of ways I can search.

Finally, I found the reason I keep getting error message

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

is I didn't login mysql using 'root' user...

I used 'root' to login then solved this...